# Is there a python plug in that can export Blender rendering data to a CSV File

Tags: rendering

I am currently in the process of upgrading my animation equipment, and I want to track machine performance.  In order to do this I need to extract or export how long it takes to render an entire project.

The Data I want to track is:

How long it takes to render one frame
The time the Render Started
The time the Render Ended

I need an accurate way of doing this, doing it manually isn't an option especially when you have more than one machine to manage.

Comment: Check the Metadata tab in Render properties. All the information is written to the files when they are rendered. You can read the metadata from frames with python.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the information from metadata written into the image (check what metadata to save in *Metadata* tab inside *Render* panel):

```
import os

string = ""
with open("PATH_TO_IMAGE", "rb") as file:
    byte = file.read(1)
    while byte and string[-4:] != "IDAT":
        char = byte.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        if char.isprintable():
            string += char
        byte = file.read(1)
file.close()

render_time_pos = string.find("RenderTime")
if render_time_pos > 0:
    time_string = ""
    i = render_time_pos + 10
    while (string[i].isdigit() or string[i] in ":") and i < len(string):
        time_string += string[i]
        i += 1
    times = [int(i) for i in time_string.split(':')]
    times.reverse()
    print("frame took %02d sec" % sum([a*b for a,b in zip(times,[1,60,3600])]))
else:
    print("render time metadata not found")
```